# Pgadmin-insert rows into table from other table by procedure

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures

I have already created table `f_table` with columns `quarter` and `sums`. Showing error as:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "SELECT".
```

Function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func4()

RETURNS void AS

$BODY$

BEGIN

insert into f_table  values
(
SELECT

tab1.quarter,

sum(tab2.tot)

FROM 

tab1

INNER JOIN 

tab2

ON

tab1_key=tab2_key

GROUP BY(tab1.quarter)

order by (quarter) asc

distributed by(quarter));

END;

$BODY$

LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

Can anyone help me with this?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you mean `tab1.key = tab2.key`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its is solved no need of distributed by because its not a table creation, its jus an insert.

after removing distributed by its working fine.

Thanks for ur responses.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is INSERT..SELECT ,remove VALUES.This will work only if f_table has 2 columns,if not you need to specify the columns

```
insert into f_table  (somecol,someothercol)
(
SELECT
tab1.quarter,
sum(tab2.tot)
FROM 
tab1
INNER JOIN 
tab2
ON
tab1.key=tab2.key
GROUP BY(tab1.quarter)
order by (tab1.quarter) asc
distributed by(tab1.quarter))
```

Comment: ya "insert into values" is the error.it is jus "insert into"    but  with this am getting ERROR:  syntax error at or near "DISTRIBUTED"